# remove space between paragraph and unordered list

Tags: html, css

```
<p>Text</p>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
</ul>
 <p>Text 2</p>
```

How do i remove the vertical space between paragraph and the list.

To be more specific - how do I reduce the bottom margin/padding of the p tag ONLY when followed by an unordered list.  All the answers I see here remove the space after all p tags - that's not what was asked.

Comment: do you want to only do this with css or can you change the markup too?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors in a way similar to the following:

```
p + ul {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

This could be helpful because `p + ul` means select any `<ul>` element after a `<p>` element.

You'll have to adapt this to how much padding or margin you have on your `<p>` tags generally.

Original answer to original question:

```
p, ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

That will take any EXTRA white space away.

```
p, ul {
    display: inline;
}
```

That will make all the elements inline instead of blocks. (So, for instance, the `<p>` won't cause a line break before and after it.)

Answer (score 12):

One way is using the immediate selector and negative margin. This rule will select a list right after a paragraph, so it's just setting a negative margin-top.

```
p + ul {  
   margin-top: -XX;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This simple way worked fine for me:

```
<ul style="margin-top:-30px;">
```

Answer (score 5):

I got pretty good results with my HTML mailing list by using the following:

```
p { margin-bottom: 0; }
ul { margin-top: 0; }
```

This does not reset all margin values but only those that create such a gap before ordered list, and still doesn't assume anything about default margin values.

Answer (score 4):

```
p, ul{
     padding:0; 
     margin:0;
}
```

If that's not what your looking for you'll have to be more specific

Answer (score 2):

You can (A) change the markup to not use paragraphs

```
<span>Text</span>
<br>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
</ul>
<span>Text 2</span>
```

Or (B) change the css

```
p{margin:0px;}
```

Demos here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnpVu/1

Answer (score 2):

Every browser has some default styles that apply to a number of HTML elements, likes p and ul.
The space you mention is likely created because of the default margin and padding of your browser. You can reset these though:

```
p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

You could also reset all default margins and paddings:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

I suggest you take a look at normalize.css: http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a definition list with an unordered list inside it. It solves the issue of the unwanted space above the list without needing to change every paragraph tag.

```
<dl><dt>Text</dt>
<dd><ul><li>First item</li>
<li>Second item</li></ul></dd></dl>
```