# How can I add padding to my html bullet point list within an email body in VBA?

Tags: html, css, vba, outlook

I can't figure out how to add padding/indents on the two list items below in the html body (lines 4 and 5 of .html body). It looks like I need to add some padding via CSS, but I do not know how to do that.

```
Sub Email_File()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailAddress As String
    Dim xMailAddress2 As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim attch As String
    Dim subj As String

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("IOM Denial.xlsm")
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailAddress = Workbooks("IOM Denial.xlsm").Sheets("Home").Range("B7").Value
    xMailAddress2 = Workbooks("IOM Denial.xlsm").Sheets("Home").Range("B13").Value
    attch = wb1.Sheets("Home").Range("B21").Value
    subj = wb1.Sheets("Home").Range("B17")


    With xOutMail
        .To = xMailAddress
        .CC = xMailAddress2
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = subj
        .HTMLBody = "<p>Operations Leadership,</p>" & _
                    "<p>An inventory performance summary of your submitted IOM requested products is attached. The IOM Summary tab displays the families that are approved or denied based on whether they met the minimum performance turn threshold.</p>" & _
                    "Products are evaluated for performance by family" & _
                    "<li>Approved products will be scheduled the same as before, based on forecast availability and prioritized by tier productivity</li>" & _
                    "<li>Denied products are due to a minimum turn threshold of productivity that is not met</li>" & _
                    "<p>Attached is an inventory performance report based on the family of products that are requested in the associated IOM.  This includes your turn and tier performance, inventory and sales information, the minimum turn threshold and national rank for your territory and decision of Yes/No for approval.</p>" & _
                    "<p>In addition - we have included three tabs that provide potential opportunities for redeployment within your territory.  Each tab report shows your productivity in each family: by account, by demand model (SISO) and evaluating loose shelf inventory and/or inventory contained in sales team and sales associate locations.</p>" & _
                    "<p>For those product families where the turn threshold is not met, (NO in column J) please review the performance metrics.  Utilizing the 3 tabs, evaluate the productivity of the identified Parked account turns, site demand model kit delta and misc inventory locations that carry this product family and work to reallocate / rebalance the inventory to meet the need of this particular IOM.</p>"
        .Attachments.Add attch
        .Display '.Send
    End With


    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is basically what I am wanting to do with those two lines, just can't figure out how to specifically write the code within VBA

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.padding {
  padding-left: 2cm;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The padding-left Property</h1>

<p>This is a text with no left padding.</p>
<p class="padding">This text has a left padding of 2 cm.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the head at the start of the `.body` or in the element declaration.  As @Ozan says

Comment: There's no `<ul>` or `<ol>` in your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a style block and/or inline css like this:

```
.HTMLBody = "<style type='text/css'> li.padded {margin-left:70px}; p.padded {margin-left:100px};</style>" & _
         "<p>Paragraph 1</p>" & _
         "<p>Paragraph 2</p>" & _
         "Products are evaluated for performance by family" & _
         "<ul><li class='padded'>List item 1</li>" & _
         "<li style='margin-left:50px'>List item2</li>" & _
         "</ul><p>Paragraph 3</p>" & _
         "<p>Paragraph 4</p>" & _
         "<p class='padded'>Paragraph 5</p>"
```

Single quotes and double quotes are more or less interchangeable in HTML, so use single quotes there to avoid having to deal with any escaping for your VBA string building.

Note you're missing `<ul>` or `<ol>` around your `li` items

Comment: Except now there is a break between the "Products" line and the first list item that I don't want?

Comment: Which two lines?

Comment: "Products" and the 1st list item

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759229/remove-space-between-paragraph-and-unordered-list

Comment: Worked well in conjunction with removing the line break after.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, this is called inline css

```
<li style="padding-left:5px"> your texts </li>
```

Also padding have left, right, top and bottom options if you are interested in too. I suggest you learn css, if you are to delve in web development.

Edit: I saw your edit now, you can use it like this.

```
<style>
.padding { 
  padding-left: 2px;}
</style>
// Below line will work now
<p class="padding">This text has a left padding of 2 cm.</p>
```

Comment: @zbreeden007 I've edited my answer. Can you try it? Also try <li style='padding-left:5px'> your texts </li> -- this is with single quote. Since you have already use double quote in your asp. Maybe this can work.

Comment: Getting an error with double quotes and not working with single quotes

Comment: @zbreeden007 Can you try this too <li style=&quot;padding-left:5px&quot;> I think this may work since its formatting used in asp.

Comment: Still nothing, sorry.

Comment: I think your method works, but the quotations in vba are causing it to error out.

Comment: You have to learn how can you use additional quotations in VBA to find your exact solution. I can only help at css side. You may also ask another question regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

This did exactly what I needed. Added indented bullet points and removed the line break between the "Products" line and the first list item line.

```
With xOutMail
        .To = xMailAddress
        .CC = xMailAddress2
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = subj
        .HTMLBody = "<html> <head> <style> li.padding { margin-top: -10px; } </style> </head>" & "<p>Operations Leadership,</p>" & _
                    "<p>An inventory performance summary of your submitted IOM requested products is attached. The IOM Summary tab displays the families that are approved or denied based on whether they met the minimum performance turn threshold.</p>" & _
                    "Products are evaluated for performance by family<br>" & _
                    "<ul><li class='padding'>Approved products will be scheduled the same as before, based on forecast availability and prioritized by tier productivity<br>" & _
                    "<li>Denied products are due to a minimum turn threshold of productivity that is not met" & _
                    "</ul><p>Attached is an inventory performance report based on the family of products that are requested in the associated IOM.  This includes your turn and tier performance, inventory and sales information, the minimum turn threshold and national rank for your territory and decision of Yes/No for approval.</p>" & _
                    "<p>In addition - we have included three tabs that provide potential opportunities for redeployment within your territory.  Each tab report shows your productivity in each family: by account, by demand model (SISO) and evaluating loose shelf inventory and/or inventory contained in sales team and sales associate locations.</p>" & _
                    "<p>For those product families where the turn threshold is not met, (NO in column J) please review the performance metrics.  Utilizing the 3 tabs, evaluate the productivity of the identified Parked account turns, site demand model kit delta and misc inventory locations that carry this product family and work to reallocate / rebalance the inventory to meet the need of this particular IOM.</p>"
        .Attachments.Add attch
        .Display '.Send
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Without testing your full code, I just distilled it down to rendering the proper HTML to prove it works.  Here is the code that should do it:

```
Dim html As String

html = "<html> <head> <style> li.padding { padding-left: 2cm; } </style> </head>"

html = html & "<p>Operations Leadership,</p>" & _
       "<p>An inventory performance summary of your submitted IOM requested products is attached." & _
       "The IOM Summary tab displays the families that are approved or denied based on whether they met the minimum performance turn threshold.</p>" & _
       "Products are evaluated for performance by family" & _
       "<li class='padding'>Approved products will be scheduled the same as before, based on forecast availability and prioritized by tier productivity</li>" & _
       "<li class='padding'>Denied products are due to a minimum turn threshold of productivity that is not met</li>" & _
       "<p>Attached is an inventory performance report based on the family of products that are requested in the associated IOM.  " & _
       "This includes your turn and tier performance, inventory and sales information, " & _
       "the minimum turn threshold and national rank for your territory and decision of Yes/No for approval.</p>" & _
       "<p>In addition - we have included three tabs that provide potential opportunities for redeployment within your territory.  " & _
       "Each tab report shows your productivity in each family: by account, by demand model (SISO) and evaluating loose shelf " & _
       "inventory and/or inventory contained in sales team and sales associate locations.</p>" & _
       "<p>For those product families where the turn threshold is not met, (NO in column J) please review the performance metrics.  " & _
       "Utilizing the 3 tabs, evaluate the productivity of the identified Parked account turns, site demand model kit delta and misc inventory " & _
       "locations that carry this product family and work to reallocate / rebalance the inventory to meet the need of this particular IOM.</p>"

html = html & "</body> </html>"

Open "c:\cdh\foo.html" For Output As #1
Print #1, html
Close #1
```

And to give you some confidence that it does indent, this is what the rendered HTML looks like in a browser:

[image]

Hard to guess what the issue was without seeing the style applied in the actual VBA, but give this a run and see if it works in lieu of your approach of manual bullets and indentation.