# Remove spacing before list in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I have the following Markdown string:

```
`log-level` (optional)<br>
Sets the minimal log level messages need in order to be printed to stdout.

Allowed values:
- `debug`
- `warning`
- `error` (default)
```

GitHub as well as Stack Overflow render it like this (blockquote added for visual distinction):

> `log-level` (optional)
>  Sets the minimal log level messages need in
> order to be printed to stdout.
>
> Allowed values:
>
> - `debug`
> - `warning`
> - `error` (default)

([screenshot from GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7tDa.png))

---

As visible here and in the screenshot, the Markdown renderer adds spacing between the last paragraph ("Allowed values") and the first list item.

Checking the generated HTML shows why:

```html
<p><code>log-level</code> (optional)<br>
Sets the minimal log level messages need in order to be printed to stdout.</p>
<p>Allowed values:</p>
<ul>
<li><code>debug</code></li>
<li><code>warning</code></li>
<li><code>error</code> (default)</li>
</ul>
```

The text "Allowed values" is placed in an own `<p>` tag, and there is a margin between the `<p>` and the following `<ul>`.

---

Is there a way to reduce or get rid of that space, such that it roughly matches the space between list items?

Comment: Original Markdown does something even different: without an empty line between "Allowed values" and the list items, these are not even converted into an <ul>, see here: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/dingus

Comment: <p> tag is block-level element, it make whatever is inside on the new line. Is it about this the question?

Comment: @Vega Your comment led me to finding a small mistake in my question. Apparently the browser places a margin of 16px below `<p>`, as well as above `<ul>` (even when I remove the `<p>` tag). So the question seems to be rather about removing the margin of both elements (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7759229/8528014)).

Comment: @Vega Yes, this may work, if one can add custom CSS, which does not seem to be possible with all Markdown renderers. E.g., it looks like GitHub does not allow inserting custom `<style>` tags, so just adding the CSS from the referenced question is not sufficient.

Comment: Can you use inline style? Sorry, I am not sure what is the use case of that markdown. Is this helpful? https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cthpzy?file=index.html

Comment: @Vega: Yes, almost! You brought me onto the right track. The `style` attribute is still ignored (for both SO and GitHub Markdown), but I did not think of directly using HTML tags. Based on your snippet, I removed the `<p>` for the "Allowed values" line: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTN42.png). This removes the spacing completely, and is quite near to a perfect solution. Feel free to post that as an answer :)

Comment: I am glad you found the solution. Please do post your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

The spacing is caused by the bottom margin of the `<p></p>` tags wrapping each paragraph.

There is a workaround if your Markdown parser supports HTML: Some parsers (e.g., [Markdig](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig), which Stack Overflow uses) don't generate `<p></p>` tags when you put text directly below another explicit `<p></p>` tag:

```
<p>...</p>
Allowed values:

* `debug`
* `warning`
* `error` (default)
```

generates

> ...
>
> Allowed values:
>
> - `debug`
> - `warning`
> - `error` (default)

[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRlio.png)

Whether that really looks better or makes sense from an accessibility aspect, is another question.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but there is no way that I know of to do what you're asking. A possible workaround to this would be to make your list a sub-list by adding an equal amount of spaces to sub-bullets. See below:

```
`log-level` (optional)<br>
Sets the minimal log level messages need in order to be printed to stdout.

- Allowed values:
  - `debug`
  - `warning`
  - `error` (default)
```

> `log-level` (optional)
>  Sets the minimal log level messages need in
> order to be printed to stdout.
>
> - Allowed values:
>
>   - `debug`
>   - `warning`
>   - `error` (default)